# Why the Gibb's phenomenon doesn't occurre when arithmetic means are used?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Why the Gibb's phenonmenon doesn't occurre when arithmetic medias are used?

The arithmetic means of an serie $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n$ is the sequence of numbers $\sigma_n$ defined by
$$\sigma_n= \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} s_k$$
where each n is in $\mathbb{N}$ and $s_k$ is a partial sum of the series. If $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sigma_n$ exists, then we say that the series is summable by arithmetic means to this limit. It seems to me that this concept is also known as [Cesàro summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_summation).

Now, if we apply this definition to the Fourier series of an function $f$ with period $2 \pi$, then we get each arithmetic mean $\sigma_n$ is a function of $x$
$$\sigma_n=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} S_k(x)$$
where for each $k$
$$S_k(x)=\frac{1}{2}A_0+ \sum_{m=1}^{k} (A_m \cos mx +B_m \sin mx)$$
is a partial sum of the Fourier series for $f$, and $A_m$ and $B_m$ are the usual Fourier coefficients for $f$.

On the other hand, we know that
$$\sigma_n(x)=\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x+u)F_n(u)du $$
where $F_n(x)=\frac{1}{n}\left ( \frac{\sin (nu/2)}{\sin(u/2)} \right )^{2}$ is the Fejér's kernel.

My attempt is none because I don't know how to start. I considered to use the fact that if $f$ is continuous and has period $2 \pi$, then $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sigma_n(x)=f(x)$ holds uniformly for all $x$ values, but the Gibb's phenomenon occurs on points of discontinuity (jump discontinuity) for f. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The Fejér kernel $F_n$ is nonnegative, so qualitatively speaking it acts like a weighted average when you convolve it with $f$. This constrains the result of the convolution. For example, if $f$ is a periodic "square wave" that oscillates between values of $-1$ and $1$, and $\sigma_n = f * F_n$, then $\sigma_n(x)$ must be between between $-1$ and $1$ for all $x$. There can't be any Gibbs-style "overshoot." The Dirichlet kernel takes on both positive and negative values and therefore does not have this property.

Comment: Just a minute... I don't know that is a convolution, I haven't covered that topic yet

Comment: By convolution $\sigma_n = f * F_n$ I simply mean the integral you indicated: $$\sigma_n(x)=\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x+u)F_n(u)du.$$ This is the definition of the convolution of $f$ and $F_n$. Convolution is a hugely important concept in Fourier analysis, which is why it gets its own name.

Comment: I don't understand why it acts like a weighted average